# How to throw 404 on bad request in .net core 2.0 route

Tags: asp.net, api, routes, asp.net-core-2.0

In my startup file I have below code

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   // app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()            
        );
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseExceptionHandler();


    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Web API running!");
    });
}
```

I'm using angular from front end side and whenver there's bad route from UI .net core send status 200 with Web API running message which is bad.
I want to throw 404 when requested with bad routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because `MVC` middleware would pass the request to the next middleware when it doesn't find any route for the request.

So the request would hit the last middleware that you wrote which says `"Web API running!"`

Why do you need that? Either delete that middleware or at least you can configure it to only work with specific path.

```
app.Map(new PathString("/monitor"), monitorApp =>
{
    monitorApp.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Web API running!");
    });
});
```

Comment: I have many controllers and Action methods.I cannot give one specific path and validate only that. How do I handle that?  I want last middleware to show if the API is up when it's launched initially.

Comment: you are not validation only one path. now all the path would either hit your actions or would send 404. and if you want to see if your api is running you can see in `yoursiteurl/monitor`

Comment: It requires '/' infront of monitor i.e. /monitor otherwise it gives error.  It worked.Thank you so much